# How to gunzip sql file in Windows?

Tags: linux, zip, gzip, mysql

I have a .sql file created in Linux using:

```
mysqldump --opt db_name | gzip > backup_file_name.sql
```

I need to use it in Windows. 7-zip can open it, but when extracting, it says "Data Error in backup_file_name.sql. File is Broken." I also tried http://www.gzip.org/#exe and I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try under Cygwin's gzip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to open a `.gz` file, which is just a compressed single file, while 7-zip is designed for compressed archives like `.tar.gz`.

Try downloading [gzip for Windows](http://www.gzip.org/), then run:

```
gzip -d backup_file_name.sql.gz
```

Comment: I have, and the error is "incomplete literal tree. gzip: backup_file_name.sql.gz: invalid compressed data--format violated"

Comment: @Obay - Sounds like your file is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably name it `backup.sql.gz`. 7zip won't know what a .sql file is (even if it is gzipped internally).

Comment: I did. 7zip can open, but when extracting, it says Data Error, File is broken.